# How can I move the arrows that CSS generated?

Tags: html, css

http://cssarrowplease.com/

If I go there, you'll see arrows at the top middle of the box.

How can I make the arrow be the top, but 25% (from the left) instead of middle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.arrow_box::before {
border-bottom-color: #C2E1F5;
border-width: 36px;
left: 25%;
margin-left: -36px;
}

.arrow_box::after {
border-bottom-color: #88B7D5;
border-width: 30px;
left: 25%;
margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have another question...Instead of having that border color, can I use a transparent png as the border color? The filename is called trans_white.png. How can I use that instead of that color?

Comment: If you mean to change the triangle background color, you can change it by changing the border-color, no images

Comment: What if I want .95 transparency on that border?

Comment: try this: border-bottom-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0.95)